# Is there any way to tell a browser that this is a bad URL to remember?

Tags: browser

I'm sending emails to customers, and I'm providing a custom URL for each, which when they go to, will log them in.

This is fine, except if they are using a shared browser that will remember the URL.

Is there any way at all to suggest to the browser that it shouldn't remember a URL?

**Edit:** This question has nothing to do with caching of the page.

Comment: Anyone using a shared browser should know enough to clear the history/cache/sessions after each use. It wouldn't really make sense for the URLs themselves to be able to provide this functionality.

Comment: In a better world ;) I don't trust users to do this, and I don't think that they should be concerned with this. And I don't think anyone actually does, perhaps less than 1%.

Comment: I was just thinking, maybe adding a special character or something like that could do the trick. (Or maybe creating a very long URL, but that would be bad for emails).

Comment: Perhaps including a response code like 404 or something like that could do the trick? But this would be a hack I would prefer not to use. Another http status code for this could be useful, but I can't find any that match.

Answer (score 0):

Have the link log them in once. Then make them create credentials that let them access the site in the future. Whats to stop a random person from typing in the url and gaining access to the content?

Comment: This is of low security concern and I would really like it to be as user friendly as possible. This includes not having to create/enter a password.

I'm including a random token in the URL, which acts as a password. So guessing is like guessing a password. (Except I made the password..)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can redirect them with a 301 or 302. Then the browser won't save the URL they went to. At least that work with the Mozilla based browsers and I would imagine others too.

Another way, it is uglier though is to reply with an error and include a body which does a refresh. Whether that works in most browsers, probably not. However, browsers do not cache pages that return an error (404 Page Not Found would work, you could also use 403 Forbidden.)

Other than that, there isn't much you can do. JavaScript does not allow you to temper with the history anymore...

Comment: Thank you for answering this old question! I'm gonna fiddle with it again in some time, and will get back to you!